# Facebook API returns permission error despite access token being valid

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook's API to post on a facebook page, and this the error that comes up.

```
{
  error: {
    message: '(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n' +
      '          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \\\n' +
      '          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\\n' +
      '          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \\\n' +
      '          sufficient administrative permission',
    type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 200,
    fbtrace_id: 'AcWINdvgXkS1Apmj4h4LEDZ'
  }
}
```

The message there is incorrect, as I used the token debugger to find out the following.

[image]

All required permissions seem to be there, and it is indeed a page type token.

The code is very simple.

[image]

I have a feeling this is another case of facebook's terrible error messaging. Any ideas?

Comment: are you `an admin with sufficient administrative permission` (I gather it's the second part of that error that applies)

Comment: @JaromandaX Indeed, I created the page using that facebook account

Comment: @JaromandaX about the picture...the code was on a VM and I couldn't copy it...I think it's fairly straightforward just a post request to the correct endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Oh god! After hours of debugging - the issue was that I was using a hashtag in the message, which obviously cut off the URL, making the access_token invisible.

Solution - encodeURIComponent(random_tag)

Silly mistake!